# How can I show a mirrored Android screen when I type a password?

Tags: android, android-edittext, passwords, mirroring

I am using "Mobizen Mirroring" to mirror the screen of my smartphone.
I'm trying to enter a password within the smartphone app through a mirrored computer.
However, pressing the password "EditText" turns the mirrored computer screen black.
I should see my password on the mirrored computer screen.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIMkg.png

I changed the value of the EditText property.

```
android:inputType="textPassword"
android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
```

and search keyword like mirroring, mobizen, password, edittext, etc...
But I can't found any post like my problem

The EditText code looks like this:

**EditText**

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/password_edit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

When I click the "EditText", I should be able to see the output of the mirrored computer.
Maybe it's a security policy.
Should I make it a plain EditText without a password attribute?

Comment: I use "Huawei Mate 20" smartphone.
It's Huawei setting problem.
If you use "Secure input", go Setting > Language & Input > touch Secure input.
Then The mirroring screen will then stay on.
I turned off the secure input option and the mirroring screen did not turn off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the inputType to text and add your own transformationmethod like this:

```
edittext.setTransformationMethod(new MyPasswordTransformationMethod());

public class MyPasswordTransformationMethod extends PasswordTransformationMethod {
@Override
public CharSequence getTransformation(CharSequence text, View view) {
    return new PasswordCharSequence(text);
}

private class PasswordCharSequence implements CharSequence {
    private CharSequence mText;
    public PasswordCharSequence(CharSequence text) {
        mText = text; 
    }
    public char charAt(int index) {
        return '*'; 
    }
    public int length() {
        return mText.length(); 
    }
    public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
        return mText.subSequence(start, end);
    }
}
};
```

Comment: Thank you for telling me.
If there is no other option, I may remove the password attribute and use it as you tell it.